# Python - For Loop and If Statement in calculating probability in coin toss

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, probability

Pretty new in Python here. I'm trying to calculate the conditional probability of an event occurring of a biased coin toss. I have most of the code figured out except the `if statement` portion - specifically, I'm unsure whether to use `pass` or `continue`. Even more specifically, I want the denominator to reflect number of iterations that meet the requirement, not the total number of iterations.

For example, let's say I want to calculate the probability of 6 groups given that we exceed 5 groups after 10 coin flips - the function would read as `simulate_three(1000,10,6,5)`, where the arguments represent 1000 iterations, 10 coin tosses, 6 groups, and 5 groups, respectively. Let's assume that only 500 iterations meets the requirement - thus, the denominator for `Outcome` is 500, and not 1000. However, I'm unsure if code is working properly...

```
import random
from itertools import groupby
import statistics

# Function for biased coin
def flip(p):
return 'H' if random.random() < p else 'T'

# Simulation
def simulate_three(X, N, Y, Z):
    Outcome = [] # List of results
    for i in range(X): # For loop for the X number of iterations
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(N)] # For loop for N number of coin flips
        if len(list(groupby(flips))) <= Z: # If group condition isn't met
            pass                           # Don't store value and skip
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips)))) # Otherwise, store to list
    print(sum(Outcome)/(len(Outcome)))     # Print expected value
    print((Y-(sum(Outcome)/(len(Outcome))))/statistics.stdev(Outcome)) # Print probability
```

Comment: either use `continue` or `Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips)))) if len(list(groupby(flips))) > Z`, you current if statement followed by pass doesn't accomplish anything

Answer (score 1):

The python documentation has [a great section on control flows.](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loopshttp://) In short, `pass` serves as a sort-of placeholder, while `continue` will continue on to the next iteration.

From my understanding of your description, you want `continue`, **not** `pass`. So the correct version would look like:

```
    if len(list(groupby(flips))) <= Z:
        continue
    Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
```

A more readable, explicit version of this might be:

```
    if len(list(groupby(flips))) <= Z:
        pass
    else:
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
```

And of course, the most direct version might be:

```
    if len(list(groupby(flips))) > Z:
        Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips))))
```

So in this instance, only if the `list` has a length greater than `Z` will it be added to your `Outcome`.

You could test this by forcing your `flip` function to only return `H`. If the control flow is working as intended, you'll throw a divide by zero error on your penultimate line.

Comment: Did you mean `continue` and not `pass`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code contains a few more bugs, for example you need to use **floating point division** instead of integer division (appropriate type casting) and your **conditional probability** computation formula needs to be corrected, what you are computing as probability is actually the z-score, assuming large number of trials of IID variables, here is the modified code, I think it will be useful to you:

```
import random
from itertools import groupby
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Function for biased coin
def flip(p): return 'H' if random.random() < p else 'T'

# Simulation
def simulate_three(X, N, Y, Z):
    Outcome = [] # List of results
    for i in range(X): # For loop for the X number of iterations
        flips = [flip(0.6) for j in range(N)] # For loop for N number of coin flips
        #print len(list(groupby(flips))), flips
        if len(list(groupby(flips))) > Z: # If group condition is met
           Outcome.append(len(list(groupby(flips)))) # store to list
    prob = (1.0*len(filter(lambda x:x == 6, Outcome))) / len(Outcome) # conditional probability
    expval = (1.0*sum(Outcome))/(len(Outcome)) # conditional expectation
    zscore = (Y - expval) / statistics.stdev(Outcome) # by CLT, assuming IID variables, compute the z score
    print prob
    print expval
    print zscore
    weights = (1.0*np.ones_like(Outcome))/len(Outcome)
    plt.hist(Outcome, weights=weights, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
    plt.xlabel('#Groups')
    plt.ylabel('Conditional Probability of Groups | (> 5 groups)')
    plt.title('Conditional Probability Distribution')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

simulate_three(1000,10,6,5)
# 0.551198257081 : this is the conditional probability
# 6.64052287582  : this is the conditional expectation
# -0.773961977708 : this is the z-score
```

[image]